# I am confused with onTouch(),please take a look

Tags: android

Here is my code.

When false is returned only ACTION_DOWN can be called and when true is returned all actions are okay, why?

```
aView = findViewById(R.id.a1);
aView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){  

    //@Override  
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        System.out.println("Gallery onTouch");  

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){  
            Log.e("touchtest", "ACTION_MOVE");
            System.out.println("ACTION_MOVE ");         

        }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){  
            Log.e("touchtest", "ACTION_UP");
            System.out.println("ACTION_UP "); 

        }else if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            Log.e("touchtest", "ACTION_DOWN");
        }

        return true;  
    }  

});
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case its always suggested to use switch case and you should return true in order to block other actions

```
switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  Log.e("touchtest", "ACTION_MOVE");
             return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  Log.e("touchtest", "ACTION_UP");
             return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  Log.e("touchtest", "ACTION_DOWN");
             return true;
        default:
             return false;
}
```

Hope it will work

Comment: It's ok now...why there must be return true